# Is there a shorter way to check for a value in M2M in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

In every page (`base.html`), I want to check whether `request.user` has an administrator role from my class `UserTypes` and show the admin link. Currently I do something like this:

```
{% if user.profile.user_types.all %}
    {% for user_type in user.profile.user_types.all %}
        {% if user_type.name == "ad" %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url admin:index %}" class="round button dark ic-settings image-left">Admin</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

`user.profile` is simply going from Django's `User` to my `UserProfile`.

But this seems a little verbose and clunky. Is there a simpler way? Maybe I should be writing my own custom context processor and pass a variable like `is_admin` or something, but I never wrote a custom context processor before...

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but why not just rely on `User.is_superuser`? Or if by "administrator" you mean any user that would have access to the Django admin `User.is_staff`. Seems like you're just adding extra complexity for no good reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add method `is_admin` to your `UserProfile` model moving business logic to models.

Note that construction like

```
{% if user.profile.user_types.all %}
    {% for user_type in user.profile.user_types.all %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

hits 2 sql query to your db. But `with` template tag reduces them to 1 hit.

```
{% with types=user.profile.user_types.all %}
{% if types %}
    {% for user_type in types %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Actually the best place for this is in models. But you should learn what django offers for your purpose (contrib.auth, permissions, user groups). Probably you reinvent the wheel.

Then condition `{% if user_type.name == "ad" %}` shouldn't be hard coded in your python code (especially in templates).